# ORACLE - Variable IN Clause - Function to return list of numbers

Tags: oracle, function

I'm trying to build a function that will return a list of numbers, for use in an IN clause.

The function needs one parameter (parentcustomer_id), and the function needs to run another SQL query to return the customer_id's related to that parent.

Example query usage:

```
SELECT customername 
FROM customertable 
WHERE customer_id IN myfunction(parentcustomer_id)
```

Expected Result:

```
SELECT customername 
FROM customertable 
WHERE customer_id IN (500006,500007,500008,50009)
```

The function should return a comma separated list of numbers, which is valid for the IN clause.

I've tried creating a "Type" which returns a table of numbers, but Oracle complains about "Invalid Number".

I've Googled for days, and tried countless methods to achieve this to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: post the function you have created to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create collecion.

```
create type numbers is table of number;

create or replace function ret_numbers return numbers is 
 v numbers := new numbers();
begin 
 v.extend(3);
 v(1):=1;
 v(2):=5;
 v(3):=9;
 return v;
end;



with test_data as (select level lv from dual connect by level <10)
select * from test_data where lv member of ret_numbers;
```

or

```
with test_data as (select level lv from dual connect by level <10)
select * from test_data where lv in (select * from table(ret_numbers)) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this!

I'm having difficulty with the INTO part of the select statement within the function. I'm getting an error: 

"Expression 'NUMBERS' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement"

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SUMPROD_GALAXY.ret_numbers (p_customer_id IN sumprod.customer.customer_id%type) return numbers is
 v numbers := new numbers();
 
begin
 SELECT customer0.customer_id INTO numbers
 FROM sumprod.businesspartnerpartnerrole.......`

Comment: To clarify, I had to add a parameter to the function as well (the input customer ID). The expected return is an array of other related customer ID's.

Comment: `SELECT customer0.customer_id  bulk collect INTO v FROM ....`
where v is variable declared as `v numbers` and the numbers is schema level colection created with `create type numbers is table of number;`

Comment: check out oracle's documentation and read something about collections and 'bulk collect' query

Comment: Perfect - With a little reading, and a lot of your help - all sorted! Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

why not do this in one query without the function

```
SELECT customername 
FROM customertable c
WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT parentcustomer_id 
FROM parentCustomerTable p 
WHERE p.customer_id = c.customer_id)
```

or even joint the 2 tables together and not use the IN

Comment: Yeah I can definitely do that. My reason for wanting to do it within a function is that it's a really common thing to do in our environment, and it's used many times through very large queries. The function would simplify the queries by a large margin. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

below query will give all values by comma seperated you can return the same value from a function out parameter

```
select listagg(parentcustomer_id,',') within group (order by parentcustomer_id) cnt from parentCustomerTable where parentcustomer_id = 'your input';
```